# SQL Subquery with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, subquery

I am very new to SQL and I have what appears to be a very simple task but I can't seem to get the results I know I should.

I have three tables, EMPLOYEE, SERVICE and PROPERTY.

I need to run a query in which it returns the First and Last Name from EMPLOYEE for Employees that have worked on a SERVICE job on a PROPERTY in Boston.

```
EMPLOYEE: EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName
SERVICE: EmployeeID, PropertyID
PROPERTY: PropertyID, City
```

This is what I have so far. I *think* it did what I needed but it just doesn't look right.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.LastName, EMPLOYEE.FirstName                                
FROM EMPLOYEE, PROPERTY, SERVICE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = SERVICE.EmployeeID
AND SERVICE.PropertyID = PROPERTY.PropertyID 
AND PROPERTY.City = 'Boston'
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.LastName, EMPLOYEE.FirstName;
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN SERVICE s
    ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN PROPERTY p
    ON s.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
WHERE p.City = 'Boston'
```

Note that I used `SELECT DISTINCT` here because a given employee may be associated with multiple services and properties, but we only want to report each matching employee once.

Comment: wouldnt that `SELECT DISTINCT`  cause problem if have two employee named `Jhon Doe` ? Probably need include `EmployeeID`

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO. You want to use something called a *join*. Join allows you to combine data that's stored in separate tables but linked in some manner. Your tables link as follows:

Employee links to Service through EmployeeID

Service links to Property through Property ID.

For example, imagine you have the following records in your tables

```
Employee Table
+ ---------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| EmployeeID | Lastname    | Firstname   |
+ ---------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| 1          | Biegeleisen | Tim         |
| 2          | Oropeza     | Juan Carlos |
| 3          | Anderson    | Jason       |
+ ---------- + ----------- + ----------- +

Service Table
+ ---------- + ---------- +
| EmployeeID | PropertyID |
+ ---------- + ---------- +
| 1          | 3          |
| 2          | 2          |
| 3          | 2          | 
+ ---------- + ---------- +

Property Table
+ ---------- + ---------- +
| PropertyID | City       |
+ ---------- + ---------- +
| 1          | Seattle    |
| 2          | Boston     |
| 3          | San Jose   | 
+ ---------- + ---------- +
```

You can use joins to combine these tables together using a query like this:

```
select e.*, p.city
    from Employee e
    inner join Service s on s.employeeID = e.EmployeeID
    inner join Property p on p.propertyID = s.propertyID
```

which gives you this table

```
Joined Table
+ ---------- + ----------- + ----------- + -------- +
| EmployeeID | Lastname    | Firstname   | City     | 
+ ---------- + ----------- + ----------- + -------- +
| 1          | Biegeleisen | Tim         | San Jose |
| 2          | Oropeza     | Juan Carlos | Boston   |
| 3          | Anderson    | Jason       | Boston   |
+ ---------- + ----------- + ----------- + -------- +
```

and it's on this new table that you want to apply your filtering.

```
select e.Lastname, e.Firstname
    from Employee e
    inner join Service s on s.employeeID = e.EmployeeID
    inner join Property p on p.propertyID = s.propertyID
    where p.city = 'Boston'
```

As per comments and other answers, you can get distinct results by using *select distinct* or a *group by*.

Select Distinct:

```
select distinct e.Lastname, e.Firstname
    from Employee e
    inner join Service s on s.employeeID = e.EmployeeID
    inner join Property p on p.propertyID = s.propertyID
    where p.city = 'Boston'
```

Group By:

```
select e.Lastname, e.Firstname
    from Employee e
    inner join Service s on s.employeeID = e.EmployeeID
    inner join Property p on p.propertyID = s.propertyID
    where p.city = 'Boston'
    group by e.Lastname, e.Firstname
```